"ChromeBook / Desktop" only NullPointerExcpetion caused by setBackgroundResource on null object when maximizing Activity
I am testing my android app ChromeBook support using a "Small Desktop API 32 Android 12L Sv2 x86_64" emulator.
When I click on the maximize window button, the app crash and the stacktrace does only contain android method calls / does NOT contains any method call of my own app!
Same behavior when the app is maximized and I click on the restore size ("un-maximize") button.
I search on SO and on Google issue tracker, but could not find this issue.
How I am supposed to deal with that?
(
FYI, I created an issue on Google's issue tracker.
Available here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/379534937
)
Stacktrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.package/com.my.package.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5811)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5703)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:71)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.setLightDecorCaptionShade(DecorView.java:2308)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.setDecorCaptionShade(DecorView.java:2293)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.updateDecorCaptionShade(DecorView.java:2302)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.updateColorViews(DecorView.java:1186)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(PhoneWindow.java:3041)
    at android.view.Window.setColorMode(Window.java:1266)
    at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:8014)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3657)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3864) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5811) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5703) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:71) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

